# What's the minimum level needed for unranked weapons so that the bonus exp levels them to 30?

Tags: warframe

What's the minimum level needed for unranked weapons so that the bonus exp levels them to 30?

I've been looking for a much more efficient way to get mastery points in ranks, so I go to big EXP farming spots such as Cerberus, Pluto, and Kiste, Ceres.

But I can't seem to figure out what's the minimum level I need to get the weapons from Level 0 (unranked) so that when the mission ends and the bonus exp kicks in, I can get it to Level 30, sell it, then start levelling up a new weapon?

Does the minimum level change if I use an exp booster?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "minimum level"?

Comment: @slow_excellence The level I need to hit at minimum so that at extraction my weapons become fully levelled.

Comment: You can easily check this by looking at the "mission progress" screen during a mission.  While the weapon will only display the current level in mission, the Mission Progress screen will show the current level plus the current bonus (if the mission ended immediately).  Keep in mind if you abandon the mission, you will lose the shown bonus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not easy to calculate. You get 50% bonus XP for all enemies killed by that weapon, but for team XP, you get no bonus. (Team XP is when your team kills an enemy, and you are in a certain range to that team member or enemy killed, of these I'm not sure).

So if you claim a weapon, equip it, but never use it (not even damaging the enemy), then you need all the 450.000 XP as that weapon will get only team XP and no bonus.
However if you claim that weapon, and you kill enemies with that weapon only, and you are doing Solo mission to ensure to get no Team XP, then you need 450.000 / 1.5 XP (=300.000) which is level 25 (rounded).
Of course the solution is somewhere in the middle between the two edge cases.

Comment: Awesome, just tried it out, and it works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: I need to revisit this one, as I have just completed some missions (Rep farming) with Trinity and I leveled my Unranked primary, secondary and melee weapon to level 30 in a 4 round run and they all GOT bonus XP (and surely no one used any weapon during the mission).

Answer (score -1):

This is a really hard question to ask, as it is dependent on how many mobs you kill. But here is my answer based on some research.

In [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/Warframe/comments/2bjzam/experience_gain_nerfed/) post, the OP states he is getting 10-15k for a 10 wave run. Lets assume that you get 1k per wave for ease. A weapon requires [450,000](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Affinity) to level up to 30. That would take you about **450 waves** to get to level 30. This doesn't account for longer waves and mobs that grant more experience though.

I think it would be difficult to take a weapon from 0-30 in one go, seeing that everything gets more difficult the farther you go and you are limited in the buffs you can apply to it. Honestly, it would probably be more efficient to run 10-20 waves then equip mods to be able to kill things quicker.

Comment: I'm not asking for a way to mitigate it, I'm asking for what level I  need to hit so that the bonus gets it to level 30.  Even though you wrongly assume that it's "difficult to take a weapon from 0-30", I would disagree.  It's very easy in fact, with the right team and gear.

Comment: Did you even read the answer?

Comment: "I'm guessing it takes 450 waves". Uh, in general, I can level from 0-30 in only 10 waves on Cerberus, Pluto, so your facts are a bit inconsistent.  Not only that, half of your answer is speculation, the other half completely avoids the issue and offers another solution, which is something I'm not asking for